# How to split a Polyline Geometry at a certain point in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, geometry, splitting

I have a polyline geometry and wish to split it into two different geometries, based on a given point on that line, in ArcObjects.

I have tried to find out how to do this, but to no avail. I found that there are three methods which are sort of related to what I want.

1. IFeatureEdit.Split Method This seems to do exactly what I want, but it Works on a Feature, and not on a Geometry. I Do not want to edit existing features, but copy the geometry from an existing feature, split it in two parts, and then process those parts.
2. IPolycurve.SplitAtPoint Method I though that this method would be useful, but it just adds a new vertex at the point, and does not split the polyline
3. ITopologicalOperator.Cut Method This would also work, but when I use it, giving a perpendicular line as the input paramter, I am getting an error which says 'An Internal error has occured in the geometry system.'

Is there some way of achieving what I want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use [`IPolyCurve.SplitAtPoint`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/SplitAtPoint_Method/002m000002m8000000/) and get the paths (parts) created after the split and do your processing on those. As long as the `createPart` argument is true, SplitAtPoint doesn't just add a new vertex, it inserts a new part between the split point and the end of the path.

[image]
<sub>(source: [arcgis.com](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/bitmaps/GeomSplitAtPoint.gif))</sub>

Whether this is the best approach somewhat depends on what processing you need to do however.

Comment: The SplitAtPoint method creates a new path starting at the point. So after casting to IGeometryCollection, I got two paths, which I then had to wrap to get two different polylines.

Answer (score 1):

I use interface IFeatureEdit (or IFeatureEdit2). If  you use method Split from interface IFeatureEdit, it will splits your feature, you will get 2 features. All of them will be new feature. (I mean 2 new Object IDs). However, if you use interface IFeatureEdit2, with method SplitWithUpdate, it is advance. We can get 2 features, but one is old feature and another is new feature.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. IfeatureEdit only works on features, and not on Geometries, which is what I want to do.